# Why isn't my skin uploading in Minecraft 1.9?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been having some problems with the Minecraft 1.9.2 skins. I have tried uploading multiple skins to my profile and none are showing up. As soon as I open Minecraft and load a singleplayer world, the default Steve skin shows up. Also when I try and play multiplayer on like Mineplex or Hypixel, not only is MY skin showing up as Steve everyone else's is too. 
When ever I do this I am not offline.

Comment: Does it work in 1.8.9 and below?

Comment: Sounds like an internet problem

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem before.

This is the way how I fix my skin when it doesn't show up, open up your launcher, log out your minecraft account, delete the data of your account from your launcher, close launcher. Then open the launcher again, login with your account, skin should show up. This actually works for me but I don't know how about you.

Skin changes take some time, if the way above doesn't work, be patient.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Deleting .minecraft was the problem here, but don't delete the `saves` folder (Singleplayer maps are saved in there), or `servers.dat`(Multiplayer servers are saved here).

How to delete your .minecraft folder:

1. Go to your search bar, type `%appdata%` or `%AppData%`.
2. Go to `Roaming`.
3. Right click `.minecraft`.
4. Click `Copy` and paste it anywhere else, desktop etc.
5. Delete `.minecraft` *Note: Only do that once you have a backup.*
6. When you start Minecraft, you need to login, do that and close the launcher.
7. Go back to your `.minecraft` and move or copy the important files (`servers.dat`, `options.txt`, the `saves` folder, and the `resourcepacks` folder) to your new `.minecraft` folder.
8. Start Minecraft again and make a profile with 1.9.

This is what worked for me; it may be different for other people. Changing a skin can take a while, so don't assume it will appear right away.

Comment: You can click the green check mark to select this as being the final answer.