# Minecraft Server Skin Glitch

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

When I go to play on my servers it always shows everyone as a Steve or Alex. When I tried updating to 1.10.2 it didn't work. But I'm the only one having this problem on my servers. Why? How do I fix it?

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to your search bar, type %appdata% or %AppData%.
2. Go to Roaming.
3. Right click .minecraft.
4. Click Copy and paste it anywhere else, desktop etc.
5. Delete .minecraft **Note: Only do that once you have a backup.**
6. When you start Minecraft, you need to login, do that and close the launcher.
7. Go back to your .minecraft and move or copy the important files (servers.dat, options.txt, the saves folder, and the resourcepacks folder) to your new .minecraft folder.
8. Start Minecraft again and make a profile.

(Source: [Why isn't my skin uploading in Minecraft 1.9?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/263389/why-isnt-my-skin-uploading-in-minecraft-1-9?rq=1))